# Issue with removing leading and trailing slash using regex

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to remove leading and trailing slash from a string using following code,

```
preg_replace('/^(\/)$/', '', '/tiger-cat/');
```

Output is not as expected, but its removing leading slash when I remove `$` from regex and similarly trailing slash when I remove `^`, when combined together its not working as expected. What went wrong in regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use alternation (`|`) to encode the meaning of "match a slash at the beginning OR match a slash at the end":

```
echo preg_replace('/^\/|\/$/', '', '/tiger-cat/');
```

But it is simpler to use [`trim`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) for this:

```
echo trim('/tiger-cat/', '/');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^\/|\/$
```

Try this. Replace with ``. `^(\/)$` your regex essentially search for string like `/` which has nothing except `/` from start to end. See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/88

Answer (score 2):

To do this you need to use alternation, meaning match at the beginning `^/` OR at the end `/$` of the string.

```
preg_replace('~^/|/$~', '', '/tiger-cat/');
```

But this makes no sense against the given string, when you could just do:

```
str_replace('/', '', '/tiger-cat/');
```